WordPress Multisite Plugin Activation Issue
I've set up a WordPress Multisite network and activated a few plugins using the "Network Activate" option in the Network Admin. However, despite activating them for the entire network, the plugins don't seem to be installed on the other sites within the network.
I've already checked the configuration, user permissions (I'm the only one too), and plugin compatibility (Woocommerce, SEOPress, Polylang) , but I'm still unable to get the plugins installed across all sites.
Has anyone else experienced a similar issue with Multisite setups? Any insights or troubleshooting tips would be greatly appreciated!
P.S : I've 3 sites, each one for a different country because i have different offers for different countries.
(site.com; site.fr; site.de...)

Is this a programming question as per [help/on-topic]? If so, please [edit] and add your code as a [mcve]. If not, delete here and maybe try [wordpress.se] instead.
